# In JavaScript a semi-colon is optional, but why should you use it anyway?

Tags: javascript, html, http

I know that in JavaScript it is optional to use a semi-colon, but why should you use it anyway?

Comment: wearing clothes is optional too, but you should probably wear them anyways.

Comment: @Marc B: wearing clothes is optional where you live? What country is that? :-p

Comment: Because when you do not use it, crazy things can happen.

Answer (score 4):

1. Yes, you should always use semicolons. Why? Because if you end up using a JavaScript compressor, all your code will be on one line, which will break your code.
2. It makes your code a little easier to parse, and compress
3. Personal Preference (For me its more readable)

Comment: parse compress and bundle (that's why some js libraries starts with `;`, to cover the case that other libraries missed semicolon)